# I'm very new to Gitlab and Jest unit testing. I manage to write some unit test, it is passing locally. But when deployed, it is failed

Tags: jestjs, gitlab

Below is the error:

```
FAIL tests/unit/notificationController.test.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run
    Jest worker encountered 4 child process exceptions, exceeding retry limit
      at ChildProcessWorker.initialize (node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/ChildProcessWorker.js:185:21)
Not found doctopt or pexpect Python module. Both are required
node:internal/process/promises:265
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^
[UnhandledPromiseRejection: This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). The promise rejected with the reason "Error: expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality
Expected: true
Received: false".] {
  code: 'ERR_UNHANDLED_REJECTION'
}
```

Please help me out to resolve this issue.

Comment: Where are you deploying the tests to that they're failing? Are you using GitLab CI? 
 Please update your question with more details so we can help answer it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.